# How to use Cobertura to test the coverage of benchmark Dacapo?

Tags: cobertura, dacapo

Recently, I was using a new benchmark: Dacapo(Here is the website:http://dacapobench.org/).

My teacher told me to use the Cobertura to test the branch coverage of 11 benchmarks in Dacapo. Meanwhile, I was learning Cobertura. I found that Cobertura instruments .class file and then running them to get some reports. While Dacapo is a .jar file combines many files in it. I just do not know how to test them with Cobertura.

It will appreciated if you can provide some useful advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Cobertura can instrument jar files if you use ant:](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/anttaskreference.html)

> You can also pass in jar files to be instrumented using standard ant
>   filesets. Cobertura will extract each class from the jar and
>   instrument it. If 'todir' was not specified then the original jar will
>   be overwritten with an instrumented version. Otherwise a new jar will
>   be written to the output directory.

```
<cobertura-instrument todir="${instrumented.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${jars.dir}">
        <include name="my-simple-plugin.jar" />
    </fileset>
</cobertura-instrument>
```

Comment: well, thanks for your reply. My testing .jar file is avrora-cvs-20091224.jar. While there is no .java file in it. How can I write a test or report task corresponding to this .jar file? It will be appreciated if you can provide a general build.xml file. Thanks~